# Laptop microphone is not working

Tags: windows-10, laptop, microphone, dell-xps

I have a microphone built into my laptop. It is not working in any application (for example, when I try to make a Skype or Zoom call, the application gives me a message that the microphone is not working).

I tried to follow some troubleshooting advice, but then I found other strange issues:

- When I try to open the "Microphone settings", I get into the "speech settings";
- When I try to open the "Microphone privacy settings", the Settings window just closes abruptly.

I tried to restart but the problem persists.

What is going on with my microphone settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on those symptoms, especially the Settings window auto-closing, it sounds like there could be an issue with the Capability Access Manager Service.

In Windows, search and run the 'Services' tool. In the list, locate 'Capability Access Manager Service'. Try to start it if it has stopped. If it's already running, restart it. Also set it to 'Automatic' if it wasn't already.

Comment: You are a genius! It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel, Sound, Recording. Is your Microphone there.

If not, run SFC and DISM on your machine.  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.

Run SFC /SCANNOW and allow to complete. 
Then run

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth

Restart after this and test.